# Mostrar 0 a la izquierda

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

El problema es cuando se exporta un csv, los 0 a la izquierda no se muestran, solo se muestra por ejemplo el 5 pero tendría que mostrar 0005. Estuve probando diferentes cosas pero no tengo resultados.

Les paso el código que genera el csv para exportar los datos.

```
public class ExportPage : Controller
    {
        public MemoryStream ToCSV(DataTable dtDataTable)
        {
            var memStream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(memStream);
            //headers  
            for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dtDataTable.Columns[i]);
                if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(";");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataTable.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                    {
                        string value = dr[i].ToString();
                        string Frmt = "#";
                        if (value.Contains(';'))
                        {
                            value = String.Format("\"{0}\"", value);
                            sw.Write(value);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (dr[i].ToString() == "Tratar")
                            {
                                sw.Write("Tratada");
                            }
                            else if (dr[i].ToString() == "Justificar")
                            {
                                sw.Write("Justificada");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                               
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(";");
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
            sw.Flush();
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return memStream;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido. ¿Podrías por favor agregar el código con el que guardas el CSV, y/o lo que has intentado? Esto ayudaría a agregar contexto y enfocar más la pregunta.

Comment: Cuando exportes columnas que contengan grupos de ceros a izquierda debes manejar esos campos como texto y exportarlos entrecomillados para evitar es tipo de errores. Cuando importes debes marcar o tomar igualmente sus columnas como texto.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Adicional a lo que te comentan, recuerda revisar el CSV con un editor de texto como Bloc de notas, notepad, geany, gedit o similar. Excel va a intentar darle formato a las cosas y te va a ocultar lo que realmente viaja en cada campo.

Comment: No se necesitaba el codigo para entender el problema, estaba claro desde el principio. Solo debes asegurar que el valor lo pones entre comillas. Se entendia que el csv lo estabas visualizando con el Excel por eso tomaba la celda con formato numerico quitando los ceros a la izquierda

Comment: Pudiste resolver el problema?, sino fue de ayuda mi respuesta la elimino

Answer (score 0):

Es fácil conviertes el int(si es que lo es) a string antes de exportarlo al csv.

```
int miNumero = 1;
miNumero.ToString("D4"); //Resultado igual a 0001
```

Answer (score -1):

El codigo que nos muestras podrias mencionar la fuente

[Export DataTable To CSV In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/export-datatable-to-csv-using-extension-method/)

se ve que lo copiaste y pegaste de este articulo.

En este se observa que no esta definiendo los valores dentro de `comillas`, esto lo validas rapidamente si abres el csv usando el `notepad`.

Un `csv` piensalo como archivo de excel, lo cual trabaja con numeros. Si una celda define el formato numerico los ceros a la izquiera no tienen sentido, como seguramente habras aprendido en la clase de Matematicas.

La unica forma de que queden los ceros es que ese valor lo definas entre comillas.

[Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Veras en la especificacion que la doble comillas indica cadena de texto

---

Por otro lado puedes ayudarse con librerias como ser

[CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

para generar el csv serializando una class que definas con la estructura mapeando esta con los campos que tendra el archivo

Comment: A una pregunta incompleta, una respuesta incompleta. ¿Por qué no le pides que incluya el código correspondiente?

Comment: que codigo ves necesario para indicar que debe respetar la especificacion de la notacion de un csv ?

Comment: La pregunta tiene unas etiquetas, habla de un código que genera algo. La pregunta en sí es vaga, al igual que tu respuesta-comentario. Sí, hay que seguir una especificación. ¿Cómo se aplica eso a la implementación del OP? Treinta y tres mil puntos de rep después, eso debería [estar clarísimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: No se que tiene que ver los puntos que uno tenga con la capacidad de dar una respuesta, sino es la correcta la eliminare y si le ayuda a resolver el problema bueno mejor. Si la pregunta es vaga entonces la cerraran.